# ComoboBox Insert New Item to database automatically

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am using a combobox in VB .net to show customer's name. They also can type new names if they wish. Can I somehow save these new names in my sql database dynamically?

What I mean is if the name is new and does not exist in my database, can it be automatically saved to the database?

My combobox is bound to my name table.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox is bound to a datatable, then you should be able to use a DataAdapter to update the database table based on your datatable.

You could possibly also make this automatic by tying it into the combobox Validated event.